# StackExchange.Redis ConnectRetry does not work as expected

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Please help me to figure out why StackExchange.Redis does not make the connection retries which I expect.

So, I have a few integration tests for the connection retry. Each of them is passing individually but when I run two of them, one fails.
I am trying to configure StackExchange.Redis connection retrying as this:

```
var configurationOptions = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(_configurationProvider.RedisPublishConnectionString);
configurationOptions.ReconnectRetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(2000);
configurationOptions.ConnectRetry = 5;
```

So as you can see the number of retries is 5 and the time between each retry is 2000. As the result I expect that in the worst case it will take more than 10000, however, my tests are failing. It takes less than 10000.

Comment: Depending on your redis provider it can take more than 10 seconds to connect.  I suggest you allow at least that much before retrying.  If you can share a connection between your tests either by segregating your test keys or by clearing the cache completely, you can connect once at the ClassInitialize or similar method, you may get better performance.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns, from your answer I see you didn't read what the problem is about. It does not work the way you say. Sometimes it is 4 seconds only and never 10.

Comment: Either I configure it incorrectly or there is a bug in StackExchange.Redis.

Comment: You need to increase the connection time limit.  Try it.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns, how it related to ReconnectRetryPolicy? As I know connection timeout is 5 seconds where it should reconnect each 2 seconds. So it means there is nothing to do with the connection timeout. However, I know this advice will work. So connection timeout means overall connection timeout?

Comment: I see it somehow affects overall duration, however, the test is still failing sporadically.

Comment: As I understand it only prolongates connection timeout for one connection but retries still do not work.